# Hide authoring information programmatically in a content type

Tags: nodes, hooks

How do I programmatically hide the *Authored by* part in a content type using hooks?

Comment: You know you can disable this manually by editing the article content type and unchecking `Display author and date information.` in the **Display settings** section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need to hide the *Authored by* part basing on some conditions you check at run-time. If you need to hide that only for a content type, for example for the *Article* content type, then you can change settings in admin/structure/types/manage/article.

> [image: screenshot]

If you want to hide that information basing on the user ID of the user who created the node, then you could use the following code.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];

  // Remove that information if the node has been created from the user #1.  
  if ($node->uid == 1) {
    $vars['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
    $vars['submitted'] = '';
    $vars['user_picture'] = '';
  }
}
```

Notice I am setting the same variables set by [`template_preprocess_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x), which uses the following code.

```
  // Display post information only on certain node types.
  if (variable_get('node_submitted_' . $node->type, TRUE)) {
    $variables['display_submitted'] = TRUE;
    $variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['name'], '!datetime' => $variables['date']));
    $variables['user_picture'] = theme_get_setting('toggle_node_user_picture') ? theme('user_picture', array('account' => $node)) : '';
  }
  else {
    $variables['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
    $variables['submitted'] = '';
    $variables['user_picture'] = '';
  }
```

The template files used by Drupal core check `$display_submitted` before rendering `$submitted` and `$user_picture`. Probably Drupal core sets also `$variables['submitted']` and `$variables['user_picture']` for those template files that render them without checking first `$display_submitted`.

Comment: thx that's exactly what i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

This variable is added in [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x), which is the second step in [template processing](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7.x).

These processors pass the variables by reference, so in any of the lower hooks (you can use a theme or a module to implement [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x)), you can alter this variable.

So in your module or theme (change MYMODULE with theme name), use this code:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
}
```